# Why is Android Studio missing "palette" from View -> Tool Windows?

Tags: android, palette

(https://i.postimg.cc/QtncTRRr/palettemissing.png)

Palette tool is missing in latest version of Android Studio? I did not see any answers to this from anywhere, except some vague explanation that after "split" update you can find some tools in the split window.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it I guess.

It is gone from tool windows menu it seems, was removed most likely. But it will appear automatically if you start a new project with empty activity and start to modify an .xml file.

[https://ibb.co/qn2m0qX](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJydl.png)